# Pandas - Explanation on apply function being slow

Tags: python, pandas

Apply function seems to work very slow with a large dataframe (about 1~3 million rows).

I have checked related questions here, like [Speed up Pandas apply function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363908/speeding-up-pandas-apply-function), and [Counting within pandas apply() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267210/counting-within-pandas-apply-function), it seems the best way to speed it up is not to use apply function :)

For my case, I have two kinds of tasks to do with the apply function.

First: apply with lookup dict query

```
f(p_id, p_dict):
    return p_dict[p_dict['ID'] == p_id]['value']

p_dict = DataFrame(...)  # it's another dict works like lookup table
df = df.apply(f, args=(p_dict,))
```

Second: apply with groupby

```
f(week_id, min_week_num, p_dict):
    return p_dict[(week_id - min_week_num < p_dict['WEEK']) & (p_dict['WEEK'] < week_id)].ix[:,2].mean()

f_partial = partial(f, min_week_num=min_week_num, p_dict=p_dict)
df = map(f, df['WEEK'])
```

I guess for the fist case, it could be done with dataframe join, while I am not sure about resource cost for such join on a large dataset.

My question is:

1. Is there any way to substitute apply in the two above cases?
2. Why is apply so slow? For the dict lookup case, I think it should be O(N), it shouldn't cost that much even if N is 1 million.

Comment: What is your first part of the question trying to do? From the definition of `f`, I have some suspicion it's not doing what you want it to do. Perhaps you should add small examples of the dataframes and the expected results.

Comment: Thanks Ami, for the first question, for example, p_dict is a country id with country name lookup table, I want to query country name with country id as input, if no country id exists, return NA :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Concerning your first question, I can't say exactly why this instance is slow. But generally, `apply` does not take advantage of vectorization. Also, `apply` returns a new Series or DataFrame object, so with a very large DataFrame, you have considerable IO overhead (I cannot guarantee this is the case 100% of the time since Pandas has loads of internal implementation optimization).

For your first method, I assume you are trying to fill a 'value' column in `df` using the `p_dict` as a lookup table. It is about 1000x faster to use `pd.merge`:

```
import string, sys

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

##
# Part 1 - filling a column by a lookup table
##
def f1(col, p_dict):
    return [p_dict[p_dict['ID'] == s]['value'].values[0] for s in col]

# Testing
n_size = 1000
np.random.seed(997)
p_dict = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [s for s in string.ascii_uppercase], 'value': np.random.randint(0,n_size, 26)})
df = pd.DataFrame({'p_id': [string.ascii_uppercase[i] for i in np.random.randint(0,26, n_size)]})

# Apply the f1 method  as posted
%timeit -n1 -r5 temp = df.apply(f1, args=(p_dict,))
>>> 1 loops, best of 5: 832 ms per loop

# Using merge
np.random.seed(997)
df = pd.DataFrame({'p_id': [string.ascii_uppercase[i] for i in np.random.randint(0,26, n_size)]})
%timeit -n1 -r5 temp = pd.merge(df, p_dict, how='inner', left_on='p_id', right_on='ID', copy=False)

>>> 1000 loops, best of 5: 826 µs per loop
```

Concerning the second task, we can quickly add a new column to `p_dict` that calculates a mean where the time window starts at `min_week_num` and ends at the week for that row in `p_dict`. This requires that `p_dict` is sorted by ascending order along the `WEEK` column. Then you can use `pd.merge` again.

I am assuming that `min_week_num` is 0 in the following example. But you could easily modify `rolling_growing_mean` to take a different value. The `rolling_growing_mean` method will run in O(n) since it conducts a fixed number of operations per iteration.

```
n_size = 1000
np.random.seed(997)
p_dict = pd.DataFrame({'WEEK': range(52), 'value': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 52)})
df = pd.DataFrame({'WEEK': np.random.randint(0, 52, n_size)})

def rolling_growing_mean(values):
    out = np.empty(len(values))
    out[0] = values[0]
    # Time window for taking mean grows each step
    for i, v in enumerate(values[1:]):
        out[i+1] = np.true_divide(out[i]*(i+1) + v, i+2)
    return out

p_dict['Means'] = rolling_growing_mean(p_dict['value'])

df_merged = pd.merge(df, p_dict, how='inner', left_on='WEEK', right_on='WEEK')
```

Comment: Thanks andrew, really nice and kind for the first question :)  But I think you may misunderstand my second question, as week_id is input parameter, for example, week_id = 5, min_week_num = 2, then I want to query mean of p_dict['WEEK'] value with 3-4, while week_id = 6, query with 4-5, so I guess it's not equivalent to move it out.

Comment: @linpingta yes of course. I was thinking of math, not coding! I deleted that part of the answer.

Comment: So any way to solve that?  I know maybe I should put it to another question, but any advise I'll be appreciated :)

Comment: It looks like you want `min_week_num` to stay fixed while `week_id` changes. Is that correct?

Comment: yes andrew, week_id changes as different rows of dataframe, while min_week_num could be treated as a const value here

Comment: @linpingta did that edit help with your second question? If not, maybe you should post a new question that includes minimal, complete and verifiable example.