# Find if some strings are in a pandas data frame ( row wise and column wise operation )

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6

Hello stackoverflowers!!

I have the following data frame

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['a', 'alike', 'b', 'x', 'a'],
                          'column2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'unlake', 'like']})

  column1 column2
0       a       a
1   alike       b
2       b       c
3       x  unlake
4       a    like
```

And I would like to create another column that has 1 if any of the following strings

```
check = ['like', 'lake', 'lik']
```

is in any of the two columns.

I started with this:

```
any([check1 in dataframe['column1'][1] for check1 in check]) # for one value this works
```

however when I want to do it for the whole column I do not get the expected result

```
dataframe[['column1']].apply(lambda row: any((check1 in row for check1 in check)), axis = 1) # this works but does not give the expected
```

I am propably missing something.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join your substrings together using the regex "or" operator `|` and then apply the `pd.Series.str.contains` method like so:

```
dataframe['substr_match'] = dataframe.apply(\
  lambda col: col.str.contains('|'.join(check))).any(axis=1)
#   column1 column2  substr_match
# 0       a       a         False
# 1   alike       b          True
# 2       b       c         False
# 3       x  unlake          True
# 4       a    like          True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, you first go over the columns and you do a vectorized operation and then you use any for each row.. what if you could not use the contains for the whole vector but only for one value?

Comment: @GeorgeSotiropoulos, I'm sure this method is sufficient for your use case. But worth noting `df.apply` is generally vectorised only in notation (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38708239/9209546).

Comment: @GeorgeSotiropoulos `apply` still works on each value of a pandas Series individually, if that's what you mean (i.e. `contains` already works one value at a time, in this case). Try calling `dataframe.apply(lambda col: col.str.contains('|'.join(check)))` on its own if this is unclear.

Comment: @cmaher Thanks for your answers, I am coming from R and DataTables so I still have to find my steps with pandas

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df.isin(check).any(axis=1),1,0) #this is for an exact match
```

Expanding to see if it contains any of the items

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['a', 'alike', 'b', 'x', 'a'],
                      'column2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'unlake', 'like']})
check = ['like', 'lake', 'lik']
pattern = '|'.join(check)
mask = np.column_stack([df[col].str.contains(pattern, na=False) for col in df])
df['check'] = np.where(mask.any(axis=1),1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine np.logical_or with pd.Series.str.contains. This assumes partial matches are permitted.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['a', 'alike', 'b', 'x', 'a'],
                   'column2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'unlake', 'like']})

test_str = '|'.join({'like', 'lake', 'lik'})

df['Test'] = np.logical_or(df['column1'].str.contains(test_str),
                           df['column2'].str.contains(test_str))


# output
# column1 column2 Test
# a a False 
# alike b True 
# b c False 
# x unlake True 
# a like True
```