# Working of pandas.apply() with functions

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add few calculated columns to a panda dataframe. Some of these columns require the values to be passed to specific functions.

I came across some behavior that I did not understand.
With reference to the following code snippet

```
from numpy.random import randn
from pandas import Dataframe

def just_sum(a,b):
    return a + b

# 1,000,000 columns with random data
df = DataFrame(randn(1000000, 2), columns=list('ab'))

df['reg_sum'] = df.a + df.b
#works almost instantly

df['f_sum'] = df.apply(lambda x: just_sum(x.a, x.b), axis = 1)
# takes little more thatn 30 seconds
```

1. Why is the apply method taking so much time ?
2. Is this the right way to do this ? If not then what is ?

PS : Somebody suggested using Cython. Will that really affect performance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question as there were 2 parts to it.

As @Orenshi said, the apply function doesn't take advantage of the vectorization.
The right way to do this is to [vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) the function. The spippet in the question can thus be written as :

```
from numpy.random import randn
from numpy import vectorize
from pandas import Dataframe

def just_sum(a,b):
    return a + b

# 1,000,000 columns with random data
df = DataFrame(randn(1000000, 2), columns=list('ab'))

vector_sum = vectorize(just_sum)

df['f_sum'] = vector_sum(df.a, df.b)
#works almost instantly
```

Answer (score 2):

The `apply` function doesn't take advantage of the vectorization... Every time the function is called it's creating a brand new series so for say millions of rows that's a lot of IO overhead.

Check out a Github issue and see the discussion [Pandas Issue 11615](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11615)

This accepted answer in this other StackOverflow post makes mention of it as well.

[Pandas - Explanation on apply function being slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697404/pandas-explanation-on-apply-function-being-slow)