# Convert timestamps in seconds to hh:mm:ss time

Tags: python, pandas, time, timedelta

I have a `df` with one `column` displaying time in seconds. I'd like to convert those to `hh:mm` or `hh:mm:ss`.

If the time goes over standard 24hr time I'd still like it to be in `hh:mm:ss`. Not `'n' days hh:mm:ss`.

To provide an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

ts1 = ['21000', np.nan, '40000', np.nan, '49000', '100000']
ts2 = [0, 2, 'yy', 3, 'yy', 'yy']
ts3 = [0, 2, np.nan, 3, 4, np.nan]
d =  {'X': ts1, 'Y': ts2, 'Z': ts3}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Output:

```
        X   Y    Z
0   21000   0  0.0
1     NaN   2  2.0
2   40000  yy  NaN
3     NaN   3  3.0
4   49000  yy  4.0
5  100000  yy  NaN
```

I can perform this on a single `string` using:

```
t = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=21000))
```

Output t:

```
5:50:00
```

But how would I pass the same function to an entire column?

```
#t_col = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=df['ts1']))
```

Intended Output:

```
          X   Y    Z
0   5:50:00   0  0.0
1       NaN   2  2.0
2  11:06:40  yy  NaN
3       Nan   3  3.0
4  13:36:40  yy  4.0
5  27:46:40  yy  NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) followed by some messy string formatting to convert days into hours:

```
def formatter(x):
    x = str(x)
    return str(int(x[-8:-6])+int(x.split('days')[0])*24).zfill(2) + x[-6:]

df['TD'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['X'].fillna(0).astype(int), unit='s')\
             .apply(formatter)

print(df)

        X   Y    Z        TD
0   21000   0  0.0  05:50:00
1     NaN   2  2.0  00:00:00
2   40000  yy  NaN  11:06:40
3     NaN   3  3.0  00:00:00
4   49000  yy  4.0  13:36:40
5  100000  yy  NaN  27:46:40
```

Comment: Works well @jpp

Answer (score 0):

**A more step-by-step approach**

First, let's create our new column and be rid of the pesky `NaN` values

```
In [156]: df['new_column'] = df.X.fillna(0)

In [157]: df
Out[157]:
       X   Y    Z new_column
0  21000   0  0.0      21000
1    NaN   2  2.0          0
2  40000  yy  NaN      40000
3    NaN   3  3.0          0
4  49000  yy  4.0      49000
5  80000  yy  NaN      80000
```

Then we can deal with creating the deltas by using a `lambda` function based on the code you had written. Note that we have to cast the values of the new column to `int`s for the `seconds` parameter of `timedelta`.

```
In [158]: df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(x['new_column'])), axis=1)

In [159]: df
Out[159]:
       X   Y    Z new_column
0  21000   0  0.0   05:50:00
1    NaN   2  2.0   00:00:00
2  40000  yy  NaN   11:06:40
3    NaN   3  3.0   00:00:00
4  49000  yy  4.0   13:36:40
5  80000  yy  NaN   22:13:20
```

**Using a one-liner**

Building on what we wrote before, we need to eliminate the `NaN`s and then convert the entire series firstly to `int`s and then to `timedelta`s.

```
In [173]: df['td'] = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_numeric(df.X.fillna(0)), unit='s')

In [174]: df
Out[174]:
       X   Y    Z new_column       td
0  21000   0  0.0   05:50:00 05:50:00
1    NaN   2  2.0   00:00:00 00:00:00
2  40000  yy  NaN   11:06:40 11:06:40
3    NaN   3  3.0   00:00:00 00:00:00
4  49000  yy  4.0   13:36:40 13:36:40
5  80000  yy  NaN   22:13:20 22:13:20
```

This approach should be faster as `apply` is quite [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697404/pandas-explanation-on-apply-function-being-slow)

As per your comment, to be consistent with the `NaN`s, you can use this

```
df['td'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['td'] if x['X'] is not np.NaN else None, axis=1)
```

Comment: Also, can we remove the 00:00:00 before or after converting?

Comment: @PeterJames123, you're redefining the question. this is beyond the scope of what you initially asked

Comment: Not really? The NaN's were fine. Now I need to remove those. What if the time is actually 00:00:00. I won't be able to differentiate.

Comment: i was referring to the comment that you deleted where you were asking me to code for times > 24 hours. your first question is within the scope and I have updated my response to answer it

Comment: Aww sorry. I could add those. All good. I'll just do a .replace