# apply on date difference returns NaT

Tags: python, pandas, date, apply

I'm trying to add a negative day to all the days in a list

```
def datediff(xdate):
  return(xdate - timedelta(days=1))

data_ = [['tom', '2022-12-01'], ['nick', '2022-12-01'], ['juli', '2021-06-08']]
data_ = pd.DataFrame(data_, columns = ['Name', 'eventdate'])

pd.DataFrame(index=data_.eventdate, data=data_, columns=['eventdate']).apply(datediff)
```

However, the eventdate, that should contain the original date minus 1, is all NaT.

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example including sample data?

Comment: I've included sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`pd.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html) to do date manipulations in a `DataFrame`.

```
In [47]: data_ = [['tom', '2022-12-01'], ['nick', '2022-12-01'], ['juli', '2021-06-08']]
    ...: data = pd.DataFrame(data_, columns = ['Name', 'eventdate'])

In [48]: data
Out[48]:
   Name   eventdate
0   tom  2022-12-01
1  nick  2022-12-01
2  juli  2021-06-08

# data.eventdate is a string so we convert it to a datetime before subtracting a timedelta
In [49]: data.eventdate = data.eventdate.astype('datetime64') - pd.Timedelta('1 day')

In [50]: data
Out[50]:
   Name  eventdate
0   tom 2022-11-30
1  nick 2022-11-30
2  juli 2021-06-07
```

You should typically avoid using `Dataframe.apply` when you can. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38708239/5491375) as to why it can be quite slow.