# Pandas get postion of last value based on condition for each column (efficiently)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the information in which row the value `1` occurs last for each column of my dataframe. Given this last row index I want to calculate the "recency" of the occurence. Like so:

```
>> df = pandas.DataFrame({"a":[0,0,1,0,0]," b":[1,1,1,1,1],"c":[1,0,0,0,1],"d":[0,0,0,0,0]})
>> df
   a  b  c  d
0  0  1  1  0
1  0  1  0  0
2  1  1  0  0
3  0  1  0  0
4  0  1  1  0
```

Desired result:

```
>> calculate_recency_vector(df)
[3,1,1,None]
```

The desired result shows for each column "how many rows ago" the value `1` appeared for the last time. Eg for the column `a` the value `1` appears last in the 3rd-last row, hence the recency of `3` in the result vector. Any ideas how to implement this?

Edit: to avoid confusion, I changed the desired output for the last column from `0` to `None`. This column has no recency because the value `1` does not occur at all.

Edit II: Thanks for the great answers! I have to calculate this recency vector approx. 150k times on dataframes shaped (42,250). A more efficient solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: and why the recency for the 3rd column should be `1` (in your output) ?

Comment: Because it is the (first)-last (like second-last, third-last, etc) row. Or in other words I start counting at `1` and not `0`. Of course you could start counting from zero like in array slicing. That is just a choice of preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop-less solution which is faster & cleaner:

```
>> def calculate_recency_for_one_column(column: pd.Series) -> int:
>>     non_zero_values_of_col = column[column.astype(bool)]
>>     if non_zero_values_of_col.empty:
>>         return 0
>>     return len(column) - non_zero_values_of_col.index[-1]

>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[0,0,1,0,0],"b":[1,1,1,1,1],"c":[1,0,0,0,1],"d":[0,0,0,0,0]})

>> df.apply(lambda column: calculate_recency_for_one_column(column),axis=0)

a    3
b    1
c    1
d    0
dtype: int64
```

Sidenote: Using `pd.apply()` is slow ([SO explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697404/pandas-explanation-on-apply-function-being-slow)). There exist faster solutions like using `np.where` or using `apply(...,raw=True)`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940265/pandas-apply-custom-function-on-all-columns-increase-efficiency) for details.

Answer (score 0):

With this example dataframe, you can define a function as follow:

```
def calculate_recency_vector(df: pd.DataFrame, condition: int) -> list:
    recency_vector = []

    for col in df.columns:
        last = 0
        for i, y in enumerate(df[col].to_list()):
            if y == condition:
                last = i

        recency = len(df[col].to_list()) - last
        if recency == len(df[col].to_list()):
            recency = None

        recency_vector.append(recency)

    return recency_vector
```

Running the function, it will return this:

```
calculate_recency_vector(df, 1)
[3, 1, 1, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"a":[0,0,1,0,0]," b":[1,1,1,1,1],"c":[1,0,0,0,1],"d":[0,0,0,0,0]})
df.apply(lambda x : ([df.shape[0] - i for i ,v in x.items() if v==1] or [None])[-1], axis=0)
```

produces the desired output as a `pd.Series`  , with the only diffrence that the result is float and `None` is replaced by pandas `Nan`, u could then take the desired column