# How to remove everything after the last occurrence of a delimiter?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove everything after the last occurrence of the `_` delimiter in the `HTAN Parent Biospecimen ID` column.

```
import pandas as pd
df_2["HTAN Parent Biospecimen ID"] = df_2["HTAN Parent Biospecimen ID"].str.rsplit("_", 1).str.get(0)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [41], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 # BulkRNA-seqLevel1
      2 df_2 = pd.read_csv("syn39282161.csv", sep=",")
----> 3 df_2["HTAN Parent Biospecimen ID"] = df_2["HTAN Parent Biospecimen ID"].str.rsplit("_", 1).str.get(0)
      4 df_2.head()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/strings/accessor.py:129, in forbid_nonstring_types.<locals>._forbid_nonstring_types.<locals>.wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    124     msg = (
    125         f"Cannot use .str.{func_name} with values of "
    126         f"inferred dtype '{self._inferred_dtype}'."
    127     )
    128     raise TypeError(msg)
--> 129 return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

TypeError: rsplit() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Data:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Component': {0: 'BulkRNA-seqLevel1',
  1: 'BulkRNA-seqLevel1',
  2: 'BulkRNA-seqLevel1',
  3: 'BulkRNA-seqLevel1'},
 'Filename': {0: 'B001A001_1.fq.gz',
  1: 'B001A001_2.fq.gz',
  2: 'B001A006_1.fq.gz',
  3: 'B001A006_2.fq.gz'},
 'File Format': {0: 'fastq', 1: 'fastq', 2: 'fastq', 3: 'fastq'},
 'HTAN Parent Biospecimen ID': {0: 'HTA10_07_001',
  1: 'HTA10_07_001',
  2: 'HTA10_07_006',
  3: 'HTA10_07_006'}})
```

Expected output:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Component': {0: 'BulkRNA-seqLevel1',
  1: 'BulkRNA-seqLevel1',
  2: 'BulkRNA-seqLevel1',
  3: 'BulkRNA-seqLevel1'},
 'Filename': {0: 'B001A001_1.fq.gz',
  1: 'B001A001_2.fq.gz',
  2: 'B001A006_1.fq.gz',
  3: 'B001A006_2.fq.gz'},
 'File Format': {0: 'fastq', 1: 'fastq', 2: 'fastq', 3: 'fastq'},
 'HTAN Parent Biospecimen ID': {0: 'HTA10_07_001',
  1: 'HTA10_07',
  2: 'HTA10_07',
  3: 'HTA10_07'}})
```

Comment: Can you check your output? I don't understand why the first row is still HTA10_07_001?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.replace`:

```
>>> df['HTAN Parent Biospecimen ID'].str.replace('_\d+$', '', regex=True)
0    HTA10_07
1    HTA10_07
2    HTA10_07
3    HTA10_07
Name: HTAN Parent Biospecimen ID, dtype: object
```

Explanation about regex: [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/iTyMiq/1)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df_2["HTAN Parent Biospecimen ID"] = df_2["HTAN Parent Biospecimen ID"].apply(lambda x:"_".join(x.split("_")[:-1]))
```

Comment: Don't use apply when you can use vectorization.

Comment: I m not really familiar with vectorization I m using apply a lot on work could this impact my code performance?

Comment: Apply is like a python loop. You can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697404/pandas-explanation-on-apply-function-being-slow

Comment: Yes it's much faster and more memory efficient. However here, for strings, there is no real vectorized solution

Answer (score 0):

Earlier versions of pandas had `pat` and `n` as positional arguments, such that you could do `.rsplit('_', 1)` and it would work well. For example, take a look at the docs for the function signature for [`.str.rsplit` @ pandas 1.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html):

> Series.str.rsplit(self, pat=None, n=- 1, expand=False)

Newer versions have defined `n` to be a keyword-only argument, such that you have to define `n=1` explicitly now, instead of just using `1` positionally. Take the docs for [`.str.rsplit` @ pandas 2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html):

> Series.str.rsplit(pat=None, *, n=- 1, expand=False)

Notice how `*` is defined after `pat=None`, indicating that the only way to pass the parameter `n` now is via a keyword arg.

In a nutshell, you have to change from

```
df_2[col].str.rsplit("_", 1).str.get(0)
```

to

```
df_2[col].str.rsplit("_", n=1).str.get(0)
```

and that way, it will work for all pandas versions.